# How to use CAT5e ethernet ports in house

Tags: ethernet, internet

I noticed my house has Ethernet ports on all of our bedrooms and kitchen/living room. I would love to take advantage of these by using it to connect a lot of our devices instead of using WiFi but not sure how to do that. Currently our modem/router is connected to one of our cable/co-axial. See pictures below. There are a couple of ports colored blue and white so not sure what the difference in them would be and the box in our closet has 3 color cables hanging which I think where theses ports feed to?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How many Ethernet ports are there in your house?

Comment: Everyone of these ethernet outlets should be wired back to a central location that contains the router/switch or a patch panel of some sort.  Is this the case in your house, or do those 2 ethernet cables you show in your hand connect to 2 ethernet jacks in the house,

Comment: Both blue and white appear to be Cat5e+ jacks, so they're electrically identical, which suggests that if there is a reason, then it has to do with what device is plugged into it.  It's possible the previous owners had digital phones and they wanted to keep their phone network separate from their data network.  That's pretty geeky, but plausible. Or it could be the plates with RJ-45 and F connectors are blue and the others are white.

Comment: I see 5 Ethernet ports around the house. Yeah i wasn't sure if there was a difference between the blue and white ports but it doesn't look like it. 

So the open wires pic was located in a closet on our first floor near the porch next to our electrical switch box.Upon further searching around the house, I was able to find the router/switch panel in one of the master bedrooms closets. Is it now just a matter of connecting my router/modem to this and that should get my Ethernet ports to work?

Comment: wifi is faster than cat5, especially with a patch panel doubling the connector count. If your wifi isn't fast, you need a better wifi router; new ones will be WAY faster than ones from a few years ago or something cheap that came with the service.

Comment: CAT5E, which is what the OP's panels appear to show, is still faster than WiFi.